# Inserting element DoubleLinked

Tags: java

I'm working on a method which inserts the specified element at the correct position in the sorted list and I can insert the same element several times..however my method didn't insert the element and I couldn't figure out why it doesn't insert all the element in correct position! this is my code

Comment: sorry but your code and your actual result contradicts, where is `System.out.print("Iteration:")` ?!! I only see `System.out.print("Iteration (for sorted list)")`

Answer (score 0):

Please don't post the same question to StackOverflow twice in a row. Instead edit your first question.

First of all, Java provides a basic doubly-linked list. You should use `LinkedList<E>` instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Anyway, you have two problems. The first is that you've got a special case for inserting things before the tail rather than after the tail. You have

```
if(current==tail){
    Node n = new Node(element);
    n.next = tail;
    tail = n;
    size++;
    return this;
}
```

where this should say

```
if(current == null){
    tail.next = d;
    d.pre = tail;
    tail = d;
    return this;
}
```

In addition, you need to make sure you're actually doing a doubly-linked list. That is,

```
n.next = head;
head = n;
```

needs

```
n.next = head;
head.pre = n;
head = n;
```

One more thing - do a binary search, not a linear search. It's sooo much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself, how should your foreach-loop know, how to access the values in your list? Maybe it is implemented in your Superclass, but does it work for your special list, too?

Just a theory, because i have no idea, what you have implemented in your `BasicDoubleLinkedList<T>`, but i guess this is, where you should start searching.

Have a look at the `List<E>` interface, there are several methods, you could check, if they all are implemented correctly, i don't think so. Just override them and your problems should be gone.